# Importing conv_block from resnet50

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I cant seem to import `identity_block` and `conv_block` from the resnet architecture.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/resnet50.py

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50,decode_predictions,identity_block, conv_block
```

It"s resulting in an import error.

```
 from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50,decode_predictions,identity_block, conv_block
ImportError: cannot import name 'identity_block'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code, it is inside resnet50.

```py
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50,decode_predictions,resnet50
identity_block, conv_block = resnet50.identity_block, resnet50.conv_block
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error

ImportError: cannot import name 'resnet50' from 'keras.applications.resnet50' (/home/mike/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/applications/resnet50.py)

Answer (score 0):

The official Keras library has a big change and can not be called directly by the client script in the case you mentioned. I have met the same issue and solved it as follows.

**1. Download keras.applications and put keras_applications into the current directory**

It is called as a library by the client script.

**2. Make an independent script of resnet50_custom.py**

change the original import statment

```
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

to the new statements as follows

```
from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

**3. Add the following import statement into the client script.**

```
from resnet50_custom import identity_block, conv_block
```

**4. Change "include_top=include_top" to "require_flatten=include_top"**

```
input_shape = _obtain_input_shape(input_shape,default_size=224, \
    min_size=197, data_format=None, require_flatten=include_top)
```

Cheers.